# VBA powerpoint crop selected image not selected gif

Tags: vba, add-in, powerpoint

I am writing an addin for powerpoint in VBA. I am letting users select a picture or placeholder and then I crop and scale them. But cropping is not allowed for  animated gifs. Is there a way to figure out if the selected image is an animated gif or just a normal picture?

Help much appreciated.

Sincerely,

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Havent found a way to figure out the different types. But issues was resolved with error handling. When trying to crop a gif, error gets thrown. Catch this error and continue with rest of program (skipping the cropping functionality)